# configure PHPStorm call hierarchy feature

Tags: php, intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

So in PHPStorm there's this feature to get the call hierarchy of any function, ie. given a function in the source code get places where that function gets called in other places in the codebase

The problem is supposed the function is called by call_user_func or (since I use Drupal) it gets called by theme('function_name') or drupal_get_form('function_name'), phpStorm's call hierarchy currently doesn't catch those....

Is there a way to configure PHPStorm such that it manages to catch those special function calls? --I know I can do "Find in Path" but I want this to happen in the call hierarchy feature--

Comment: As far as I know, this is an issue with all IDEs. When functions aren't called directly, they're very difficult to find. Particularly because call_user_func() and others can (and often do) contain variables, it's very hard to trace, particularly outside of execution time

Comment: You cannot -- feel free to submit Feature Request on their Issue Tracker at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI . Considering they do have special Drupal support (separate plugin bundled by default), they **may be able** to extend this functionality to support such **drupal-specific** invocations in such **clear** cases where it is obvious what function is called (i.e. `drupal_get_form('function_name')` and not `drupal_get_form($some_function)`).